# Nodejs module that returns a stream with a pipe

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I am trying to create a Nodejs module that returns a `Transform` stream. It takes as its input a readable stream. However, I would like output to be passed through another stream before being returned. For example:

```
const { Transform } = require('stream')
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream')

let myTransform = new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform: function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        callback(null, chunk.foo + 1)
    }
})

module.exports = myTransform.pipe(JSONStream.stringify('[', ',', ']'))
```

When I do this, the stream `myTransform` is ignored. I realize I could move the pipe to `JSONStream` elsewhere, for example `request('https://...').pipe(myTranform).pipe(JSONStream...)` but I would like to keep that part as part of the module.